# Void function call as expressions

Tags: c

It's clear from the C standard that general function calls are expressions from the definition:

> An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies computation of a value, or that designates an object or a function, or that generates side effects, or that performs a combination thereof. The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.
>   (6.5.1)

Since the `()` are operators and it returns a value, regular function calls are obviously expressions.

But those which don't return a value don't seem to fit with this definition. The function name itself does (as it designates a function), but this isn't a function call.

The standard does clearly say that a function call is an expression, and that it can return `void`, but this seems to conflict with the definition of an expression. What am I missing?

Comment: void functions can `generate side effects`

Comment: @GauravSingh the standard defines a side effect as modifying an object and changing state, a function call doesn't have to do that

Comment: As is clear from the [Wikipedia entry for combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), a combination, which is a selection of items from a collection, includes the selection of no items. (E.g., the number of combinations of zero items from a collection of n items is n!/(0!n!) = 1.) So a valid combination of value computations, object/function designations, and side effects is the empty combination. (Nonetheless, I expect the answer is simply that 6.5 1 was not completely thought out with regard to void.)

Comment: This does not answer the question by itself, but it is informative: C 2018 6.3.2.2 says “The (nonexistent) value of a *void expression* (an expression that has type `void`) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its side effects.)”

Comment: @EricPostpischil if you accept a void return as a value then it would pass the first part of the definition, and that quotation does appear to do that. It seems a bit of a "get out of jail hack" though, since everywhere else a value concerns a .. value, in the sense we'd normally take it.

Comment: @teppic `void` is the empty set of values and a return of `void` type is a nonexistent value, so I don't think that fits. @EricPostpischil is referring to the fact that, given they use the word "combination", we could assume that doing nothing also fits the definition.

Comment: @teppic: Acorn is correct. As mathematicians use the term, one combination of computing a value, designating an object/function, or having a side effect is the combination in which none of those are done.

Comment: @Acorn ah, I see. That language seems an extremely ambiguous choice, as most would take it to mean at least one, even if in mathematics it includes none.

Comment: By the way, note that this question can be generalized to any other expression that fits the bill, not just about function calls with `void` return type and no side-effects. For instance, consider something as simple as `(void)0`.

Comment: @Acorn That's true, but I was more interested in how returning void could be considered returning a value, rather than explicitly discarding a real value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calling a function is an expression regardless of the function's return type. C's grammar is orthogonal to its type system. They are independent pieces of the language. Grammatically `func();` is an *expression statement*.

```
expression_statement
    : ';'
    | expression ';'
    ;

postfix_expression
    : primary_expression
    | postfix_expression '[' expression ']'
    | postfix_expression '(' ')'
    | postfix_expression '(' argument_expression_list ')'
```

There are very few things you can do with a `void` result. You can't assign it to a variable since `void` variables aren't allowed. If `func()`'s result is `void` you can use four operators:

- Parentheses: `(func())`
- Comma sequencing: `func(), 42`
- Ternary operator: `42 ? func() : func()`.
- Cast to void: `(void) func()`

You can also return a `void` result:

```
return func();
```

Finally, in a `for(init; condition; increment)` loop the three pieces are all expressions. *init* and *increment* (but not *condition*) can be `void`.

```
for (func(); 42; func()) { }
```

Few of these are useful and none are good style, but they're all legal.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting this, with the note that the language of 6.5 isn't perfect as per @Eric Postpischil's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Paragraph 1 of clause 6.5 was not completely thought out with regard to `void`. The C standard is imperfect and has a number of defects. This paragraph should be received as a general description to orient readers and is not a precise mathematical specification of what an expression is.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. I think the answer is a combination of @JohnKugelman's showing the grammatical definition and taking 6.5 as somewhat ambiguously worded.

Answer (score 1):

It is said that:

> An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that
>
> - specifies computation of a value, or
> - that designates an object or a function or
> - that generates side effects
> - or that performs a combination thereof.

The specifies computation of a value is but *one* among possibilities. The `void` function call would be the one "that generates side effects".

---

Any expression in the  expression statement in C is considered a `void` expression. [C11 6.8.3 Expression and null statements p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.3p2):

> 2. The expression in an expression statement is evaluated as a `void` expression for its side effects.***153)***
>
> ***153)*** Such as assignments, and function calls which have side effects.

i.e. in the expression *statement*

```
a = 5;
```

`a = 5` is a *void* expression that is evaluated for its side effects only, i.e. the assignment of value `5` into `a`, not for computation of a value, even though `a = 5` could be used for a computation of a value in *other contexts*. Likewise you can write `a;` and it is a legal use of an expression "evaluated for its side effects", even though it has none. It does not cease to be an expression there.

The LHS of a comma operator is a void expression. A void expression can be used in `? :` - then both branches will be void expressions and the entire expression in itself will be a void expression.

Comment: @Scheff the standard says a function call only generates side effects if it changes an object or accesses a volatile object, thus the side effect answer is a dead end here I think.

Comment: It is not a dead end, the only useful `void` function is one with side effects. That there is a way to write a non-useful `void` function without side effects does not refute that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala whether the function is useful or not isn't relevant to the question though. A function that doesn't have side effects isn't an expression if that is the only determining factor (which it's not).

Comment: @teppic a function call is an expression. The point is that the **syntactic** possibility is that it is evaluated for side effects. Whether someone writes functions that do not  have side effects **and** do not return values for the sake of an argument is totally besides the point.

Comment: @Scheff it's just about definitions, not what the compiler does -- whether or not a function has side effects doesn't decide on whether it's an expression or not, the standard literally says that. It's just not very clear about void functions.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Note that `a` refers to an object, so it fits the definition. Also, note that `a = 5` is not a void expression -- it is an assignment expression and has a type different than `void`, so it also fits the definition. It is the expression of an expression statement that is evaluated as if it was a void expression, but the expression itself is not necessarily a void one. Same for the other comments about the comma operator and the conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

An expression in C can be void.
Such an expression has not a value and then it cannot be assigned to an object.
Moreover,  any expression can be cast to void.